# Prevent Overlapping

Tags: three.js

I have many cubes in the scene randomly placed in a circle
I want to place a gltf model in a static position and remove the cubes there (In other words, there should be no overlap between the cubes and the model)

I have this live example, I found a way to detect object collisions, It's Box3. I have updated the example with this feature. The problem is that `.intersectBox` returns false when the objects (fox model with cubes) collide. [link](https://codepen.io/Teymoor/pen/ZEoyGQp) , I checked and found that `box3` 'Min' and 'Max' of models and cubes are wrong. Although the helpers shows the right place. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is your question how to identify the cuboids to be removed, or how to remove a specific cuboid?

Comment: This is what I mean. Where cylinders exist, boxes do not exist.
This means that a box should not be created from the beginning at the point where the cylinder is